# Ошибка 405 (method not allowed) используя ajax method post laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, post, get

Здравствуйте есть вот такой скрипт ajax

```
$.ajax({
                    url:'/load_content/',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data:{
                        count: $('.artikl').length
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                    $("#content_in").append(data);
                }
                });
```

Роутер выглядит так:

```
Route::post('/load_content/', 'MyController@load_content');
```

При запуске скрипта выдает

```
405 (method not allowed)
```

Функцию в  `VerifyCsrfToken.php` добавил
Когда метод меняю на `GET` срабатывает как надо.  Вот в чем еще загвоздка на `OpenServer` `POST` срабатывает. Как решить проблему или найти источник ее?

Answer (score 4):

Если запрос с вашего же сайта, зачем добавлять исключение (которое вы неправильно добавили судя из ошибки), вам нужно установить через `ajaxSetup` чтобы передавался `header` при ajax запросе и всё, устанавливаете мета тег:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

И после этого настраиваете `ajaxSetup`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

В [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) это всё есть и хорошо описано.

Comment: Так почему на OpenServer всё работает?

Comment: Мета и был прописан, добавил вот так:
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
$.ajax({
                    url:'/load_content/',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data:{
                        count: $('.artikl').length
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                    $("#content_in").append(data);
                }
                });
Все равно ошибка.

Comment: @Domilola а в headers есть X-CSRF-TOKEN?

Comment: А где можно отследить есть ли в headers X-CSRF-TOKEN?

Comment: @Domilola в браузере или дебажить в коде

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте убрать слеш в конце урла при вызове ajax:

```
url:'/load_content'
```

В роуте тоже желательно слеши убрать:

```
Route::post('load_content', 'MyController@load_content');
```

Answer (score 2):

Тоже была такая небольшая проблема. В документации не работает подобный код. Поэтому просто в data передавайте текущий токен. Вообще не понимаю откуда они взяли X-CSRF-TOKEN, когда во всех формах ключ был "_token". И в headers кстати даже "_token" не работает. Поэтому это как-то вдвойне ошибочная инфа. Возможно в старых версиях было.

```html
data: {
 "_token" : token
}
```